# Canopy 32 & 64 bits version

Tags: enthought

I´m currently using Windows 8.1 and Canopy 2.1.9 - 64 bits.

May I also install the 32 bits version, so I have both versions installed on the same machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, but there is no reason to. Canopy v2 can create and use multiple python environments,  including multiple python versions and both 32 and 64 bits. Canopy 32 bit is only necessary on a 32-bit operating system. You can find details in the Canopy documentation and on the enthought support knowledge base:

https://docs.enthought.com/canopy/2.1/configure/python-environments.html

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002376586-Canopy-2-1-Managing-and-switching-between-Python-2-7-and-3-5-environments

https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version

Comment: Added links to answer